# How to rebuild an array with no repeats & other limits?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have an app that allows people to serve custom assessments. I've built a new scoring mechanism at a client's request that allows the participant to select between two questions according to which is more accurate for them. The problem is that I need to randomize the questions, insure that two questions from the same category do not appear together, & limit it so two questions from the same two categories are only compared three times.

I've tried to adapt code/answers from other questions here, but none of them directly apply and I'm having difficulty adapting the ones that are the closest.

Here is a sample from my original array containing the questions (already randomized, but without the other criteria)...

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2087
            [category_id] => 287
            [question] => Question would appear here
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2068
            [category_id] => 286
            [question] => Question would appear here
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2067
            [category_id] => 286
            [question] => Question would appear here
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2073
            [category_id] => 286
            [question] => Question would appear here
        )

    [4] => Array
            [question_id] => 2029
            [category_id] => 283
            [question] => Question would appear here
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2083
            [category_id] => 287
            [question] => Question would appear here
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2084
            [category_id] => 287
            [question] => Question would appear here
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2036
            [category_id] => 283
            [question] => Question would appear here
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2062
            [category_id] => 285
            [question] => Question would appear here
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2045
            [category_id] => 284
            [question] => Question would appear here
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 2052
            [category_id] => 285
            [question] => Question would appear here
        )
)
```

There are 30 questions total. To insure there is an even distribution, questions from the two categories should only be compared three times.

How do I build a new array from this one using PHP that...?

1. Randomizes the questions
2. Pairs questions between different categories
3. Insures categories are only compared three times

--UPDATE--
Adding MySQL table structure in case it's easier to build an advanced query to do what I'm looking for...

```
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `question_id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `question` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `question_id` (`question_id`),
  KEY `questions_ibfk_1` (`category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `questions_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `category_id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

--UPDATE--

I'm posting this as a MySQL question as I believe building the right query will suffice for what I'm needing. If you have an idea on how to do so, please post to the following question...

[How do I build a MySQL query that pulls distinct pairs with a limit on how many times categories can match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56176612/how-do-i-build-a-mysql-query-that-pulls-distinct-pairs-with-a-limit-on-how-many)

If you know a way to accomplish this via arrays, would still love to know how to do so. Thanks!

Comment: _two questions from the same two categories are only compared three times._  What does that even mean???

Comment: Your question / category have id, so you get them from database ? Maybe work on your query to get what you want using your criteria?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have 5 categories with 6 questions each. I need to insure questions aren't shown from the same category (should always be selected between two different categories) and two categories should only be compared three times. Per the array above, questions from categories 285 & 286 should only be paired up three times total.

Comment: @MickaelLeger Thought of that, but not sure how to build a MySQL query to get what I'm needing, either. I'll update the question with the appropriate table elements in case that is a better/easier solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally came up with that worked (after attempting unsuccessfully to build the query I needed to accomplish the same thing)...

The original array `$theresults` contains all 60 questions from the 5 different categories. I begin by building an array of all the question categories...

```
// Create array of all categories
$allcategories = array();
$this->db->select('category_id');
$this->db->where('template_id',$template_id);
$query_thecategories = $this->db->get('categories');
$number_thecategories = $query_thecategories->num_rows();
if ($number_thecategories>0) {
    foreach ($query_thecategories->result() as $row_thecategory) {
        $thecategory = 'cat_' . $row_thecategory->category_id;
        $$thecategory = '0';
        $allcategories[] = $row_thecategory->category_id;
    }
}
```

Then I use the following function to pull all the unique combinations of categories...

```
function array_search_by_key($array, $key, $value) {
    if(!is_array($array)) {
        return [];
    }
    $results = [];
    foreach($array as $element) {
        if(isset($element[$key]) && $element[$key] == $value) {
            $results[] = $element;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}

$uniquecombos = uniquecombos($allcategories, 2);
```

Lastly, I loop through each of the combos to pull questions that match each category in the pair and store the result in a new array. (I loop it three times because each category pairing will be used three times (10 combinations of question pairs x 3 loops = 60 questions.) I also remove each question I pull from the original `$theresults` array to insure there are no duplicates...

```
// Create an empty array to capture the paired questions
$pairs = array();

// Loop through unique combos array 3 times to build pairings
for($combos = 1; $combos <= 3; $combos++) {
    foreach ($uniquecombos as $theset) {
        // Get two categories in pair
        $firstcategory = $theset[0];
        $secondcategory = $theset[1];

        // Gather other arrays which matches each category
        $matchesfirst = array_search_by_key($theresults,'category_id',$firstcategory);
        shuffle($matchesfirst);
        $matchessecond = array_search_by_key($theresults,'category_id',$secondcategory);
        shuffle($matchessecond);

        // Get question from each new array & add; remove selected question from the original array
        $pairs[] = $matchesfirst[0];
        unset($theresults[$matchesfirst[0]['question_id']]);
        $pairs[] = $matchessecond[0];
        unset($theresults[$matchessecond[0]['question_id']]);
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone else!