# How do I build a MySQL query that pulls distinct pairs with a limit on how many times categories can match?

Tags: mysql

I have an assessments app that pulls questions from different categories out of two MySQL tables. I need to write a query that will pull pairs of questions with the following criteria...

1. Not the same question
2. Not from the same category
3. Questions from categories should be matched 3 times

I have 5 categories (let's call them A-E) with 12 questions each, so the query should pull 3 pairs of questions for each unique combination of categories... (never re-using the same question)

```
A-B = 3 pairs of questions
A-C = 3 pairs of questions
A-D = 3 pairs of questions
A-E = 3 pairs of questions
B-C = 3 pairs of questions
B-D = 3 pairs of questions
B-E = 3 pairs of questions
C-D = 3 pairs of questions
D-E = 3 pairs of questions
E-C = 3 pairs of questions

30 pairs of questions = 60 questions total
```

Here is my (simplified) MySQL table structure...

```
CREATE TABLE 'questions' (
    'question_id' int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'category_id' int(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
    'question' text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('question_id'),
    UNIQUE KEY 'question_id' ('question_id')
);

CREATE TABLE 'categories' (
    'category_id' int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'category' varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('category_id'),
     UNIQUE KEY 'category_id' ('category_id')
);
```

Comment: Lots of ones is so dull.

Comment: @Strawberry not sure what you mean. I was just trying to show that the query needs to pull three pairs of questions from each of those category pairs (3 total).

Comment: Understood. Right now I don't have a MCVE for an example. I've built an array of all questions per category & then shuffled the result. This only satisfies #1 out of the 3 criteria, though.

I asked a question first about how to build a new array with the limits I need (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171290/how-to-rebuild-an-array-with-no-repeats-other-limits?noredirect=1#comment98969434_56171290) but I was informed that it would be best to do it via query. Not sure how to do a more advanced MySQL query, though.

Comment: Good luck then.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this query is what you want. It returns the first three pair os questions for each combination of categories. If you are using the version 8 or superior of MySQL, this query may be simplified using Window Functions. Previous versions do not support ROW_NUMBER.

```
SELECT catA.*, catB.*, qA.*, qB.* FROM (
  SELECT cat_a, cat_b, q_a, q_b, 
  @row_n := IF(@cat_a = cat_a AND @cat_b = cat_b,  @row_n + 1, 1) AS row_n,
  @cat_a := cat_a,
  @cat_b := cat_b FROM (
    SELECT a.category_id cat_a, b.category_id cat_b, a.question_id q_a, b.question_id q_b 
    FROM questions a
    JOIN questions b ON a.category_id <> b.category_id AND a.category_id < b.category_id
    ORDER BY a.category_id, b.category_id
  ) qlist
) rows 
JOIN categories catA on catA.category_id = rows.cat_a
JOIN categories catB on catB.category_id = rows.cat_b
JOIN questions qA on qA.question_id = rows.q_a
JOIN questions qB on qB.question_id = rows.q_b
WHERE rows.row_n <= 3
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afedabf/1

Comment: Thanks! Just realized I had typed the wrong number of questions somehow. (Sorry about that - just updated my original post to correct it.) I actually have 12 questions for each of the 5 categories. Tested your SQLFiddle and added the correct number of questions. It's pulling too many questions for each of the category pairs, though. It should be pulling three unique questions (can't repeat) for category pair 1-2, three more for pair 1-3, and so on. See the updated SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/517882/6

Comment: Also, how can I pull the category & questions names in addition to the category_ids & question_ids? I tried modifying the query you built but it kept breaking.

Comment: @ChrisEdiger, I updated the SQLFiddle and the query to fix the repetition bug and added the joins to bring all the info you need.

Comment: Awesome - thanks! It's really close, but one more issue I see. Once a question is used, it shouldn't be used again. We're essentially finding a way to match up all of the questions in the database correctly, but all questions need to be used & only used once. Thank you SO much for all of your help! I can't imagine how I could have figured this out on my own!

Comment: Here's the updated SQLFiddle which includes the full test table structure/data alongside your new query so you can see what I'm seeing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/517882/45

Comment: @ChrisEdiger, I don't see an easy way of removing this duplicates, once I already used the order to eliminate duplications of pairs of categories. Depending on the size of your data, maybe you should do this in memory, which is more flexible

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the effort!